Alexa is trying to play a song when i ask for "time" (zeit)
I'm from Switzerland and I speak (Swiss)German.  I often ask for the time "Alexa Zeit".  Until now that worked perfectly.
Since a few days there's a song called "Zeit" on Spotify and now when I say the magic words, Alexa plays that song instead of telling me the time.
I unlinked Spotify, delete all history I could think of in the privacy settings. but still every second time I ask for "Zeit", Alexa now tells me that it can't find the song "Zeit" on Spotify anymore.
Any idea how to fix it?

try asking Alexa a question, not just a single word

As suggested in the comments it should be fixed by rephrasing, if necessary to a complete sentence. "Alexa, wie spät ist es?" should not lead to any confusion.

It worked for years, and i'm so used to just say "alexa zeit".. it's hard to go back to a full sentence as it comes out naturally.
